# Anidacion de WebPanels

Tags: genexus

¿Me podrían decir si se puede poner un *Web Panel* dentro de otro? y si es así, ¿Cómo se puede hacer? o en todo caso, ¿Cómo pasar un id a una tabla para llenar datos, pero sobre el mismo Web Panel?

Answer (score 2):

Isaac,

Si, lo es posible. Hay dos o mas formas de hacerlo:

1. Poner 1 web component y cargar otra webpanel en el. (1 para 1)
2. Poner 1 grid freestyle con un webcomponent y cargar varias webpanels, la misma o no. (1 para n).

Creo que la 1ra opcion es el que necesita...

Comment: La pregunta aparenta denotar que los WebPanels estarían "anidados". En tal caso creemos importante tener en cuenta el orden de ejecución de los eventos de cada webcomponent tal cual se indica en este link 

http://library.gxtechnical.com/gxdlsp/pub/GeneXus/Internet/Docum/ReleaseNotes/7.5/WebComponents.htm